# simplexml_load_file ampersand in url

Tags: php

We have a simple PHP script that loads the server status from an external XML file like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://domain.com/?module=server&action=status-xml");
foreach ($xml->Group->Server->attributes() as $nodename => $value){
    if ($nodename == $param){
        return $value;
    }
}
```

When the script runs, we get a internal server error 500. Looking at the error log, we see the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/alOYI.png

Basically, the **&** in the URL is getting urlencoded (at run time, somehow) into **& amp ;**

Any idea why this is happening? This was on a apache2 /w php-fpm setup. Is this some sort of security setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is merely an error reporting feature, not an actual change in URL when the request is made. You can check if the **html_errors** option has been enabled by either the hoster or during your own install. (More information: [www.php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors))

When **html_errors** is enabled all the error-content will be converted to HTML-entities and links to the online PHP-documentation will be added. If you then check error.log on your server, you will see the entities as text instead of HTML.

Answer (score 2):

What you see there is the *HTML* output of a PHP error message in which `&` is converted to its respective HTML entity `&amp;`. It doesn't mean `&amp;` is sent to the server in the query string.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was worried the urls were getting translated. I now fear this is related to some other deeper issue reported here http://serverfault.com/questions/511432/what-is-the-proper-way-to-run-php-fpm-with-apache2-on-cpanel-shared-hosting-set

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) you should use it this way.

```
simplexml_load_file(rawurlencode('http://example.com/?a='.urlencode('b').'&c='.urlencode('d')))
```

Hope this helps.

[EDIT]
But be sure that the desired function on your server works. Check this by calling your URL directly from the browser. This should output an xml file.

Comment: This hasn't been applicable since 5.1

Comment: Thanks Jack, you are completely right! I did not know until now.

Comment: @cb0 Thanks for that. If I request the xml data url directly in browser, it loads. However, it fails when I do it from the simplexml_load_file function. Does this means, i need to load the xml in the way you have described?

Comment: No it does not. The way I have described it is deprecated since php 5.1 as Jack mentioned. Php since 5.1 will recognize that you call an url and will do the necessary actions.